# Error executing dynamic select query inside a stored procedure in IBM DB2

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, db2, dynamicquery

What is wrong with the below code? I am trying to execute a dynamic query inside a stored procedure in DB2. My procedure is getting created

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  get_users( in offsetValue integer,
                              in sortCol varchar(20)            
                            )
  SPECIFIC get_users
  LANGUAGE SQL 

  Re:  BEGIN

    DECLARE SELECT_STATEMENT VARCHAR(8000);
    DECLARE SQL_STATEMENT STATEMENT;

    DECLARE c_emp CURSOR FOR SQL_STATEMENT;

    set SELECT_STATEMENT = 'select * from users;';

    PREPARE SQL_STATEMENT FROM SELECT_STATEMENT;

    EXECUTE SQL_STATEMENT; 

    open c_emp;
  END Re
```

But when I call the procedure using

```
call get_users(3, 'email_id');
```

I am getting the following error

```
SQL Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=;;select * from users;END-OF-STATEMENT, DRIVER=4.24.92
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: I'd assume you need a cursor to read the data.

Comment: I have created a Cursor and later I am opening that cursor once the line is executed.. How else should I use the cursor to read the data ?

Comment: Do FETCH instead of EXECUTE? (Do OPEN, FETCH, CLOSE.)

Comment: Previously I executed the same using cursor. But it was not a dynamic query. Only when I introduce a dynamic query, I am facing this issue.

Comment: Remove that `;` directly after `select * from users`?

Comment: I tried that. I gave me an Error: SQLCODE=-518. It means that there is an error while Preparing a statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too many errors...
Try this:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  get_users( in offsetValue integer,
                              in sortCol varchar(20)            
                            )
  SPECIFIC get_users
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
  LANGUAGE SQL 

  Re:  BEGIN
    DECLARE SELECT_STATEMENT VARCHAR(8000);
    DECLARE SQL_STATEMENT STATEMENT;
    DECLARE c_emp CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR SQL_STATEMENT;

    set SELECT_STATEMENT = 'select * from users';
    PREPARE SQL_STATEMENT FROM SELECT_STATEMENT;
    open c_emp;
  END Re
  @
```

Comment: Depending on your code calling this SP, you may add 'WITH HOLD' clause to the cursor definition to avoid unexpected closing it if, for example, your calling code uses autocommit turned on and issues some other statements during fetching from the SP's result set...

Comment: What is the print statement in db2? I have tried DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE. But it isn't working. Also, I tried SET SERVEROUTPUT ON. Even this isn't working

Comment: What tool do you use to print the results? What’s the exact sequence of calls you tried? This must work in the db2 command line processor (DB2 CLP). Other tools must call internally the corresponding SP to show you the contents of an internal buffer, where your dbms_outpt.put_line calls placed their output.

Comment: how we can call the above procedure from java code??

Comment: @ashutosh Look at the [Call the set of stored procedures implemented in SpServer.java](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sample.doc/doc/java_jdbc/s-SpClient-java.html)